# Overloading template functions

Tags: playframework, overloading, template-engine, twirl

I want to have a template function like:

```
@myInput("myLabel")
```

but that it can optionally take additional parameters like:

```
@myInput("myLabel", Validation.Max(5), Validation.Min(3).....)
```

and some sort of logic inside the template function, that generates the HTML accordingly.

Now, this seems impossible with Twirl as explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/GMeWC7TjZ_c). But what is the right approach with this kind of complex template functions? Naming each of the overloading differently seems confusing and complex. Also, keeping them in separated files seems like too messy as well.

I have also heard about the Magnet Pattern, but I am not so sure how to apply this into a Twirl template.